# Socks5 connection via Network.Browser

Tags: sockets, haskell, ssh, socks, tunnel

Is it possible to use `Network.Browser` with a SOCKSv5 connection?  I opened a ssh tunnel using the Linux command line with `ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 username@remote_machine.com`.  Now I would like to be able to use use Network.Browser with this connection. ( I tried `setProxy $ Proxy "localhost:8080" Nothing` for `Network.Browser`, but this doesn't work...)

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you try [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/socks-0.4.1/docs/Network-Socks5.html#v:socksConnectTo) ?

Comment: It's better to give an explanation with a link, in case the link goes dead in the future.

Comment: @Sibi: Yes, I tried this and it seem to work. But is it possible to use this connection with the functions of Network.Browser? I don't want to re-implement Network.Browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php) can be used to SOCKS-enable anything. :P

Looking at the source code of Network.Browser, there doesn't appear to be a "tunable" that would allow it to make connections through a SOCKS proxy.  It can do an HTTP proxy, but I suspose that doesn't help much.

While it is not *quite* as friendly as Network.Browser, I'd suggest switching to [http-client](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client).  It *does* have [a hook](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.3.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v%3amanagerRawConnection) that would allow you to support SOCKS and it has functional SSL/TLS support in http-client-tls.